# Out of Memory Error when loading images to a View Pager from File

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, out-of-memory, android-drawable

I have a Viewpager using the cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2 library.  I keep getting an OOM error (see at the bottom).  I'm calling a ViewPager using the above library that resides in a fragment (see below) that is sitting in a View Pager that I'm using with a TabManager.

**EDIT** I've tried the following tasks:

1. Adding a step to recycle the bitmap  (removed per the suggestion below)
2. changed to a large heap size in the mainfest
3. Added the suggested bitmap images
4. Added a Cache
5. Added Bitmap Worker Tasks per the android suggestion
6. Added an Async Drawble

The adapter is below: **Edited**

```
public class HomeGalleryAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements OnPageChangeListener {



RequestQueue requestQueue;
int currentPage;
private LruCache<String, Bitmap> mMemoryCache;


static ArrayList<Integer> intentInfo = new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<String> quizImage = new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<String> downloads = new ArrayList<>();
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider cp;
final Context c;
SharedPreferences sp;
String density;

public HomeGalleryAdapter(Context context){
    c =context;
    cp = AmazonS3.getProvider(c);
    intentInfo.clear();
    quizImage.clear();
    sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

    mMemoryCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {
        @Override
        protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
            // The cache size will be measured in kilobytes rather than
            // number of items.
            return bitmap.getByteCount() / 1024;
        }
    };

    String cognitioID = sp.getString("Cognito","");
    density = sp.getString("screenDensity", "");


    String requestURL = "http://XXXXXX/top_5_sponsers.php?format=json&device_id="+cognitioID;


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, requestURL, null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.i("Home Gallery Adapter ", "Volley");
            try{

                JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("posts");



                for(int i=0; i < ja.length(); i++){

                    JSONObject jsonObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONObject interior = jsonObject.getJSONObject("post");

                    intentInfo.add(i, interior.getInt("iquizontap_quiz_ID"));

                    quizImage.add(i, interior.getString("QUIZ_SPONSER_IMAGE"));

                    int a = c.getResources().getIdentifier(interior.getString
                            ("QUIZ_SPONSER_IMAGE"),"drawable",c.getPackageName());

                    if(a == 0){
                        downloads.add(interior.getString
                                ("QUIZ_SPONSER_IMAGE"));
                        Log.i("added a file", interior.getString("QUIZ_SPONSER_IMAGE"));
                    }
                }
                 new imageDownloads().execute();

            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley","Error "+error);

                }
            }
    );

    requestQueue.add(jor);

    notifyDataSetChanged();


}



@Override
public int getCount() {

    notifyDataSetChanged();
    return quizImage.size();


}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {

    return view == (object);
}




@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){


    Log.i("Home Gallery Adapter", "instantiateItem");

    final int innerposition = position;
    final ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(c);
    int imageHeight = imageButton.getHeight();
    int imageWidth = imageButton.getWidth();
    String bitmapFileName = c.getCacheDir() + File.separator + quizImage.get(position).trim() + ".png";
    imageDownloadParams params = new imageDownloadParams(bitmapFileName, imageWidth, imageHeight);



    if(cancelPotentialWork(bitmapFileName, imageButton)) {

       final Bitmap bitmap = getBitmapFromMemCache(bitmapFileName);

        if(bitmap != null) {

            BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageButton);
            final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable =
                    new AsyncDrawable(c.getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.quizontap_default), task);


            imageButton.setBackground(asyncDrawable);
            task.execute(params);
        }

    }

    Log.i("Home Gallery Adapter", "Insitate Item after set Image");


    (container).addView(imageButton, 0);



    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public  void onClick(View v) {
            Intent quizIntent = new Intent(c,QuestionActivity.class);
            quizIntent.putExtra("company", getItem(innerposition));
            quizIntent.putExtra("tab",1);
            c.startActivity(quizIntent);
            Log.i("intent from onClick", quizIntent.getIntExtra("company" , 1)+"");
        }
    });


    return imageButton;



}

public Integer getItem(int index){
   return intentInfo.get(index);
}



@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageButton) object);

    final int innerposition = position;
    final ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(c);

    Drawable drawable = imageButton.getDrawable();
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable){
        BitmapDrawable bd = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        Bitmap bitmap = bd.getBitmap();

        bitmap.recycle();
    }
}


 @Override
 public void onPageSelected(int newPageIndex) {
        currentPage = newPageIndex;
 }

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int newPageIndex) {

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {



}

@Override
public float getPageWidth(int position){
    return 0.93f;
}



public class imageDownloads extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Log.i("Home Gallery", "In home Gallery Image Download");
        for(int i = 0 ; i<downloads.size(); i++){

            Log.i("file name to dl",downloads.get(i));

            String fileName = c.getCacheDir()+ File.separator+downloads.get(i).trim()+".png";

            File d = new File(fileName);


            if(!d.exists() || d.length() == 0) {
                AmazonS3.createFile(downloads.get(i), c);

            }

            TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(qotSingleton.getInstance(c).getAmazonS3Client(), c);

            TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.download("quizontapimages/quizimages", downloads.get(i).trim()+ density+ ".png", d);


            observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(int fileName, TransferState transferState) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(int fileName, long l, long l1) {
                    int percentage = (int) (l/l1);

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int fileName, Exception e) {
                    Log.i("home gallery", e +"");

                }
            });

        }return "test";
    }


    protected void onPreExecute(String test) {

    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.




    protected void onPostExecute(String test) {






        notifyDataSetChanged();


}
}


class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<imageDownloadParams, Void, Bitmap>{
    private final WeakReference<ImageButton> imageButtonWeakReference;
    private String filename = "";
    private int height;
    private int width;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageButton imageButton){
        imageButtonWeakReference = new WeakReference<ImageButton>(imageButton);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(imageDownloadParams ... params){
        filename = params[0].fileName;
        height = params[0].height;
        width = params[0].width;

        final Bitmap bitmap =decodeSampledBitmap(filename, width, height);

        addBitmapToMemoryCache(params[0].fileName, bitmap);


        return bitmap;

    }

    @Override
    protected  void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap){
        if (imageButtonWeakReference != null && bitmap !=null){
            final ImageButton imageButton = imageButtonWeakReference.get();
            final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWOrkerTask(imageButton);

            if(this== bitmapWorkerTask && imageButton != null){
                imageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

        }


    }





}


public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmap(String f, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f,  options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = CommonUtilities.calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f, options);
}


public static class imageDownloadParams {
    String fileName;
    int width;
    int height;

    imageDownloadParams(String fileName, int width, int height){
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
}

static class AsyncDrawable extends BitmapDrawable{
    private final WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask> bitmapWorkerTaskWeakReference;

    public AsyncDrawable(Resources res , Bitmap bitmap, BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask){
        super(res, bitmap);
        bitmapWorkerTaskWeakReference = new WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask>(bitmapWorkerTask);
    }

    public BitmapWorkerTask getBitMapWorkerTask(){
        return bitmapWorkerTaskWeakReference.get();
    }
}


public static boolean cancelPotentialWork(String filename, ImageButton imageButton){
    final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWOrkerTask(imageButton);

    if (bitmapWorkerTask != null){
        final String bitmapData = bitmapWorkerTask.filename;

        if(bitmapData == "" || bitmapData != filename){
            bitmapWorkerTask.cancel(true);
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    return true;
}

private static BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWOrkerTask(ImageButton imageButton){
    if(imageButton != null){
        final Drawable drawable = imageButton.getDrawable();
        if(drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable){
            final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = (AsyncDrawable) drawable;
            return asyncDrawable.getBitMapWorkerTask();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public void addBitmapToMemoryCache(String key, Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (getBitmapFromMemCache(key) == null) {
        mMemoryCache.put(key, bitmap);
    }
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromMemCache(String key) {
    return mMemoryCache.get(key);
}
```

}

I'm calling it from here:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
ImageButton playquiz;
ImageButton watchvideo;
AutoScrollViewPager galleryPager;


static ArrayList <String> videos= new ArrayList<>();
static ArrayList<Integer> quizNo = new ArrayList<>();

boolean running;
HomeGalleryAdapter adapter;
View rootView;
RequestQueue requestQueue;
String cognitioID;
Context context;
Integer downloadFlag;




@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mainfragment, container, false);
    downloadFlag = 0;

    SharedPreferences accountInfo = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    cognitioID = accountInfo.getString("Cognito", "");

    context = getActivity();
    Log.i("context in MF", context + "");
    running = true;
    galleryPager = (AutoScrollViewPager) rootView.findViewById (R.id.homegallery);
    playquiz = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.playquiz);
    watchvideo = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.watchvideo);





    if(quizNo.isEmpty()) {
           QuizLoad();
            }

    adapter = new HomeGalleryAdapter(getActivity());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    galleryPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    galleryPager.setClipToPadding(false);
    galleryPager.setPageMargin(10);
    galleryPager.setInterval(4000);
    galleryPager.startAutoScroll(4000);





    playquiz.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent quizoutIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), QuestionActivity.class);
            quizoutIntent.putExtra("company", getCompanyName(galleryPager.getCurrentItem()));
            quizoutIntent.putExtra("tab", 0);

            startActivity(quizoutIntent);

        }


    });

    watchvideo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(videos.get(galleryPager.getCurrentItem()))));

        }


    });


   galleryPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if (videos.get(position).isEmpty()){
                watchvideo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else
                watchvideo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

public Integer getCompanyName(int index){

    return quizNo.get(index);
}

public MainFragment() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}





@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    running = false;
    galleryPager.stopAutoScroll();
}

@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    running = false;
    galleryPager.stopAutoScroll();

}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    running = true;
    if(quizNo.isEmpty()) {


        QuizLoad();


    }
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   galleryPager.startAutoScroll(4000);


}


public void QuizLoad(){
    Log.i("MainFragment", "quizNo is Empty");


    String requestURL = "XXX.php?format=json&device_id="+cognitioID;


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    JsonObjectRequest jor = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, requestURL, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try{

                        JSONArray ja = response.getJSONArray("posts");



                        for(int i=0; i < ja.length(); i++){

                            JSONObject jsonObject = ja.getJSONObject(i);


                            JSONObject interior = jsonObject.getJSONObject("post");

                            quizNo.add(i, interior.getInt("iquizontap_quiz_ID"));

                            videos.add(i, interior.getString("VIDEO_URL"));
                        }



                    }catch(JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }







                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley","Error "+error);

                }
            }
    );

    requestQueue.add(jor);


}
```

}

Nothing has changed but maybe the size of the images (images on the whole have actually gone down in size). I load five images in the previous activity, before this fragment is loaded, into the Cache directory and then check if they are there and if not download them.

I have tried increasing the heap size, recycling the images (see destroyItem in the adapter.  Instead when I try to initialize the adapter I get the following error: **ADDED**

```
D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB at     android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.b(SourceFile:956)
....
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 13408152)
03-28 23:53:34.144 745-745/com.brillada.quizontap E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                                                                android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 13408152 bytes
                                                                    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerNative.java:4425)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:90)
                                                                    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
                                                                    at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
```

Comment: Not much you can do but use smaller bitmaps.  Also, don't recycle your bitmap immediately after placing it in an ImageView.  It needs to be fully allocated in order for the ImageView to draw correctly.

Comment: Beyond that, try not to `recycle()`, but to *reuse* the `Bitmap` objects for loading in fresh bitmaps (see `inBitmap` on `BitmapFactory.Options`). A 4MB allocation is difficult at the best of times. Once you have one, only release it when you are very sure that you will not be needing it again. Constant allocations and releases will fragment your heap, particularly on Android 4.4 and lower.

Answer (score 0):

The following link gives some hints about how to decode images efficiently. It explains why, even if the images are not too big by nowadays standards (where we are supposed to have Gbs of memory, and you are having an issue due to 13 Mb), you have limitations imposed by the system architecture. One of the first articles tells you how to downsample the images:

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

I agree with Doug Stevenson. I would suggest to use downsampling when bringing them to memory.

Excerpt from the article:

> To tell the decoder to subsample the image, loading a smaller version into memory, set inSampleSize to true in your BitmapFactory.Options object. For example, an image with resolution 2048x1536 that is decoded with an inSampleSize of 4 produces a bitmap of approximately 512x384. Loading this into memory uses 0.75MB rather than 12MB for the full image (assuming a bitmap configuration of ARGB_8888). Here’s a method to calculate a sample size value that is a power of two based on a target width and height:

Comment: So that seemed to fix the original error, but now I'm getting a Stack Overflow error.

Comment: Well, have a look to your definition of  the LruCache:

Comment: The size is in bytes [link] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html        and this is what you have: `final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;  `  Meaning you take the maxMemory (in bytes), divide it by 1024, and then by 8, and assign it to cachesize. If you had 8Mb you are asigning 1Kb to the cache :-).